# Преобразование двух классов с одинаковыми полями

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс Order1 и экземпляр класса Order2, у обоих классов поля одинаковы, мне нужно преобразовать экземпляр из Order2 в Order1, как это сделать?
Все поля публичные.

Comment: Какая схема наследования классов ?

Comment: А почему потребовались разные классы? Поля публичные? Собственно 2 варианта у вас: вручную написать метод и явно прописать какое поле куда копируется; либо через рефлесию в цикле перебрать поля и найти им соответствующие. Ну и существуют в nuget готовые мапперы для этих целей (которые работают по второму принципу), например, Automapper.

Comment: А зачем вам это понадобилось? Если вам такое нужно, вполне возможно, у вас неправильно организована структура данных.

Comment: Нужно взять поля одного объекта и присвоить их другому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так реализовал

```
 class Order1
{
    public int OrderNum;
    public object Seller;
    public object[] goods;
    public Order1(int goodsQuantity, int OrderNum)
    {
        goods = new object[goodsQuantity];
        Seller = "Petya";
        this.OrderNum = OrderNum;         
    }        

    public static explicit operator Order1(Order2 v)
    {
        return new Order1(v.goods.Length, v.OrderNum)
        {
            OrderNum = v.OrderNum,
            Seller = v.Seller,
            goods = v.goods
        };
    }
}

class Order2 
{
    public int OrderNum;
    public object Seller;
    public object[] goods;
    public Order2(int goodsQuantity, int OrderNum)
    {
        goods = new object[goodsQuantity];
        Seller = "Vasya";
        this.OrderNum = OrderNum;
    }

 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Order1 or1 = new Order1(15, 45);
        Order2 or2 = new Order2(12, 47);
        or1 = (Order1)or2;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Ужас. К чему такие извращения? Неужели нельзя просто сделать 2 разных экземпляра одного класса? Я даже не могу придумать, где Ваше такое решение может понадобиться...

Answer (score 0):

У Вас неверно организованны данные, наследования. Ну если хочется поизвращаться, то:

```
public void Convert(object from, object to)
{
  Type tFrom = from.GetType();
  Type tTo = to.GetType();
  PropertyInfo[] pFrom = tFrom.GetProperties();
  foreach (PropertyInfo property in pFrom)
  {
    PropertyInfo propertyTo = tTo.GetProperty(property.Name);
    if (property.CanRead && propertyTo.CanWrite && property.PropertyType.Equals(propertyTo.PropertyType))
      propertyTo.SetValue(to, property.GetValue(from));
  }
}
```